# Applying multiple filters on the same data javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of data that I am reading from a json file.

I need to implement some filters that will return the correct data depending on what filters are checked.

I am using react and redux and - and the studyData is coming from either check boxes or dropdowns.

What would be the best way to filter so filters so they work well together?

At the moment they work individually but break when you use them with each other.

Here is my code:

```
function filterStudies(studyData){
  let searchTerm = studyData.searchTerm  === undefined  ? '' :  studyData.searchTerm;
  let studies = studyData.studies.filter((val)=> val.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm.toUpperCase()));

  if(typeof(studyData.isLive) !== 'undefined'){
    studies = studyData.isLive ? studies.filter((val) => val.live === studyData.isLive) : studyData.studies;
  }
  if(typeof(studyData.isCompleted) !== 'undefined'){
    studies = studyData.isCompleted ? studies.filter((val) => val.completed === studyData.isCompleted) : studyData.studies;
  }
  if(typeof(studyData.media) !== 'undefined'){
    studies = studyData.media === 'All' ? studyData.studies : studies.filter((val) =>  val.media === studyData.media);
  }
  if(typeof(studyData.environment) !== 'undefined'){
    studies = studyData.media === 'All' ? studyData.studies : studies.filter((val) =>  val.environment === studyData.environment);
  }
  return studies;
}
```

Comment: do you want to minify your code or something else? It wasn't quite clear from your question

Comment: You are always overriding `studies = ...`

Comment: I just need to return the new studyData array which has all the filters applied.

Comment: basically how do you get filters to work together rather than individually.

Comment: It depends if you want your filters to be OR or AND. If you check `isCompleted` and `media`, do you want studies with `isCompleted AND media`, or `isCompleted OR media` ? Currently it's AND.

Comment: @JeremyThille All the studies will have a set of properties related to them for example one study media would be 'TV' and isCompleted could be 'true'.  When you select the tv option and the isCompleted option I need it to apply both those filters on the data.  So I guess I do need AND?

Comment: In that case, there's no reason the code you provided should not work. What do you mean `it breaks`? Does it crash? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you well.

But anyway, at first glance, I see think your last `if` should be:

```
if(typeof(studyData.environment) !== 'undefined'){
    studies = studyData.environment === 'All' ? studyData.studies : studies.filter((val) =>  val.environment === studyData.environment);
}
```

instead of:

```
if(typeof(studyData.environment) !== 'undefined'){
    studies = studyData.media === 'All' ? studyData.studies : studies.filter((val) =>  val.environment === studyData.environment);
}
```

BTW, I would suggest to simplify your code relying on single filter that decides which items should be preserved and which ones should be discarded.

Just as an example (I **Don't understand** what exactly pretend to do your code so mine will hardly do it) but I hope it could serve as an example:

```
function filterStudies(studyData){
    let searchTerm = studyData.searchTerm  === undefined  ? '' :  studyData.searchTerm;
    let studies = studyData.studies.filter(function(val) {
        if (val.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm.toUpperCase())) return true;
        if (val.live === studyData.isLive) return true;
        if (val.completed === studyData.isCompleted) return true;
        if (studyData.media === 'All' || val.media === studyData.media) return true;
        if (studyData.environment === 'All' || val.environment === studyData.environment) return true;
        return false;
    });

    return studies;
}
```

> **NOTE:** Obviously those "if"s could be combined in single one (they perform an "or"). I tried to provide an example as close as possible
>   to your original code but, in fact, this way would be quite more
>   readable anyway...

Comment: Hmm studies is an array though that i need to return - basically it returns filtered data for a table